# Notify child components of transition state in TransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm using the `TransitionGroup` component to provide a page-transition effect that swaps an existing component out for a new one as the user moves through a journey-like interface.

```
const { stepId, children } = this.props;

<TransitionGroup className="journey">
    <CSSTransition
        timeout={300}
        classNames="journey-step"
        unmountOnExit
        key={stepId}>
        <div className="journey-step">
            {children}
        </div>
    </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

This all works great, except the children need to trigger some work as soon as they're presented. The obvious solution is to start this work on mount (using `componentDidMount()` or similar), but in some cases, this causes the UI to update whilst the transition effect is happening and causes an unpleasant UX.

Ideally, the child wouldn't start doing anything until it has fully transitioned into view. The `CSSTransition` exposes an `onEntered` event which would be the perfect trigger to start the processing, but I can't think of a good way to tie this event to the children.

I'm using ReactJS 16.2; maybe there are some newer options available to me?

This container wants to be agnostic of the children which are hosted within it, so I am looking for a solution which makes the transition event available to child component that are interested in it.

Comment: i mean you dont wanna make boilerplate code, because if you insert `<CSSTransition>` with the same class, will take the same animations

Comment: You can pass the onEntered event down to the children and they can execute it once when they are in view

Comment: Yes, having the same animations is the goal exactly. I want to re-use this style of transition in various parts of my app (with a variety of content, naturally).

Comment: @ShivamGupta Can you show exactly *how* you could pass the event to the children by modifying my code sample? That is the crux of my question 

Comment: Can you use the React Context api to pass the active step?

Comment: @JackAllan Are you asking whether I have the React Context API available to me? If so, yes, I'm using 16.2. If you're asking whether it's an option I would explore, I'm afraid I don't know enough to comment.

Answer (score 2):

[Use the React Context Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Here is an example usage for your scenario. I don't know how TransitionGroup works so this may not work for you. Here I am passing the stepId down, which will work provided the stepId changes when the transition has finished. If not you will want to update some component state in the onEntered event and pass that state down instead.

```
// Create a context
const JourneyContext = React.createContext();

// Use the provider to pass the stepId down
const { stepId, children } = this.props;

<JourneyContext.Provider value={stepId}>
  <TransitionGroup className="journey">
    <CSSTransition
      timeout={300}
      classNames="journey-step"
      unmountOnExit
      key={stepId}>
      <div className="journey-step">
        {children}
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>
  </TransitionGroup>
</JourneyContext.Provider>

// If your child is a functional component you can use the useContext hook to get the current stepId
const stepId = useContext(JourneyContext);
if (stepId === THIS_STEP) {
  // Do something...
}

// If your child is a class then you can access the context in the render method like this:
render() {
  return (
    <JourneyContext.Consumer>
      {stepId => {
        if (stepId === THIS_STEP) {
          // Do something...
        }
      }}
    </JourneyContext.Consumer> 
  );
}
```

If your child component is a class and you need to use the context value in a life-cycle method you can [use a contextType](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype).
But I'd recommend using the hooks approach if possible.